# How to draw image from URL on canvas with original quality

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to load an image from url and draw it on my canvas. My canvas takes full window size and I only want the image to be shown on the mouse position with a size of 100x100. Below is my code:

```
drawImage(imageUrl) {
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = () => {
      ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
      ctx.drawImage(image, this.state.mousePos.x, this.state.mousePos.y,
        100, 100);
    };
    image.src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png';

  }
```

the image can be drawn on the web page but the quality is pretty low. Below is the orianl image from above link:

[image]

below is the image is shown on my canvas:

[image]

You can compare two images and their quality is quite different. How can I draw a high quality of the image on canvas?

Comment: the width and height of image is well defined?

Comment: make it 158 X 158 to avoid resample jaggies. might also play with the aliasing settings if you have no subtle color gradations.

Comment: The width and height applied to the canvas from CSS would stretch it, but you didn't provide that information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('c'),ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const image = new Image();
image.onload = () => {
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(image, 50, 50,500,500);
};
image.src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66';
```

```css
canvas{
 border : 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='c' width=500 height=500/>
```

Use svg if you relay on image quality.

Comment: hi can you please help in how to get the base64 string from the above code? as toDataURL method throws cors policy error.